# Use Twitter API from one account to tweet from another account?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, tweets, twitterapi-python

Is it possible to use my twitter API registered account on account X to tweet from another account Y, which is also mine?

Comment: Nope. You'd need an access token from Y.

Comment: @ceejayoz So I should register Y for a dev account too?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you'd simply have to authenticate as account Y using OAuth 1.0a.
See https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/overview and https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/basics/authentication/oauth-1-0a for more information.

If you're using Tweepy, see https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/auth_tutorial.html.

Comment: I'm somehow unable to do this according to this manual. I have consumer_key and secret, access_token and secret from account X. How should I then login to the other account from tweepy?

Comment: Something like the example in the [Getting started section of Tweepy's documentation](https://tweepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html) should work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like Twitter made it intentionally hard to do this. Let me explain how I to do it, based on how I did it,

1. Create a developer account from your main account and get it approved
2. Create a separate Twitter account for your bot
3. In the developer portal Create a project and add an app
4. copy all the keys and secret keys while you are doing it
5. Go to user authentication settings in the app details and turn on oAuth 1.0a and OAuth (copy all the keys and keep it in a notepad)
6. go to [tw-oob-oauth-cli](https://github.com/smaeda-ks/tw-oob-oauth-cli) and download the relevant binary with respect to your OS.
7. remove the part after `tw-oob-oauth` from the file name.
8. run `./tw-oob-oauth --key ${your_consumer_key} --secret ${your_consumer_secret}`
9. `your_consumer_key` means your API key, and `your_consumer_secret` means your API secret (those are basically at the top of your copied keys or you can find them in the keys and tokens section of your app in the developer portal).
10. Follow the instructions shown in your command prompt after running the command
11. Finally You will get an `Access Token` and `Token Secret`
12. Use those two along with API key and secret to run your bot.

Hope it saves some hours of your valuable time, Cheers!